# Выдать пользователям права на управление всеми службами в Active Directory

Tags: windows, active-directory

Есть домен Windows 2016, в который входит десяток серверов, на которых крутится куча томкатов и апачей.

Задача - сделать так, чтобы члены определенной группы могли создавать, удалять, останавливать и запускать службы томкатов (или, в крайнем случае - все службы).

На каждом компьютере список нужных служб разный, пользователей много, службы постоянно появляются и пропадают. Стандартный путь - экспорт службы в список контроллера домена и разрешение через GPO этой конкретной службы - не подходит, потому что вручную все это завести и поддерживать нереально.

Админа юзерам давать не хочется.
Куда копать?

Comment: По поводу прав https://geektimes.ru/post/75090/ По поводу раздачи. Сделать группу безопасности, дать ей соответствующие права и включить в нее пользователей.

Comment: Как выдать права на одну конкретную службу я знаю. А вот как - на все? 
Их количество регулярно меняется, как и названия. Очень не хочется писать скрипт на логин, который будет считывать все службы и выдавать на них права. Криво как-то и муторно.

Comment: на все из списка, который вам нужен, или на все-все-все вообще?

Comment: Из списка, который формируется по шаблону. Т. Е. В теории я могу составить его руками. Но он типа большой - 700+ значений. Но подойдёт и просто все-все-все. Системные службы запрещено трогать отдельно.