# Выдача прав на запуск служб

Tags: windows, администрирование, active-directory, windows-server-2003

Как пользователю/группе домена выдать права на запуск/останов **любой** службы, на любой клиентской машине входящей в домен?

Все ссылки, что я нашел приводят, в конце-концов, к

```
Group Policy -> Computer Configuration -> Windows Settings ->
  Security Settings -> System Services
```

с предложением указать какими все-таки службами можно управлять.

Но мне нужны **все** службы. А самое главное - там перечислены службы, установленные на контроллере домена. А на клиентах установлены дополнительные службы

Если права на управление **всех** служб выдать невозможно, то как выдать права на управление конкретной службы, не установленной на контроллере?

Контроллер на Windows Server 2003 SP2

Comment: А локального админа дать - слишком много?

Comment: Да не хотелось бы. Машин много. Но как вариант может подойти.

Comment: А может как-то пушить с клиентов службы в виде списка, а потом этот список через powershell\cmd добавлять для юзера?

Comment: Как? `Если права на управление всех служб выдать невозможно, то как выдать права на управление конкретной службы, не установленной на контроллере?`

Comment: Ну я и написал выше, что как-нибудь набыдлокодить на павершелле. Модуль для работы с AD там точно есть. Грязные хаки в общем.

Comment: Тот же вопрос без ответа https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/662622/%D0%92%D1%8B%D0%B4%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%8C-%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%B7%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%BB%D1%8F%D0%BC-%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B2%D0%B0-%D0%BD%D0%B0-%D1%83%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B2%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5-%D0%B2%D1%81%D0%B5%D0%BC%D0%B8-%D1%81%D0%BB%D1%83%D0%B6%D0%B1%D0%B0%D0%BC%D0%B8-%D0%B2-active-directory

Answer (score 1):

Лично я давал конкретному доменному пользователю, по SID, права на запуск службы на локальной машине с помощью вот этого решения [sc config](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4436558/start-stop-a-windows-service-from-a-non-administrator-user-account).
Аналогично и Вы можете дать группе пользователей права на управление конкретными  службами.

Comment: Но вы это делали на конкретной машине? Или с контроллера?

Comment: Я это делал на локальной машине обычной последовательностью команд. То есть, данная процедура хорошо автоматизируется скриптами.